# How to send different dates within Check-in and Check-out fields within https://www.expedia.co.in/ using Selenium through Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am writing a simple code to select arrival place, departure place,arrival date and departure date in Expedia.

**Everything work perfect expect the arrival date and departure date showing same**.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/bin/geckodriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.expedia.co.in/")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "tab-flight-tab-hp").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-origin-hp-flight").send_keys("SFO")
time.sleep(2) 
driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-destination-hp-flight").send_keys("NYC")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-departing-hp-flight").send_keys("07/06/2019")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-returning-hp-flight").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='flight-returning-hp-flight']").send_keys("10/06/2019")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form[@id='gcw-flights-form-hp-flight']//button[@class='btn-primary btn-action gcw-submit']").click()
```

Output Screenshot:

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: In my Script i entered Different date for arrival and departure but it selecting same date for both arrival and departure.

Answer (score 1):

Need a little change to user script.

Click on the Return date after entering the start date. Then hit back space to remove the default date. Below is the logic.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-departing-hp-flight").send_keys("07/06/2019")
ele = driver.find_element(By.ID, "flight-returning-hp-flight")
#click on return date field
ele.click()
# remove the default date(same as selected start date) by hitting backspace
length = len(ele.get_attribute('value'))
ele.send_keys(length * Keys.BACKSPACE)
#enter the return date
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='flight-returning-hp-flight']").send_keys("10/06/2019")
```

Comment: Yes, JeffC. `ele.clear()` did not cleared the values at least with the locator that OP used.

Answer (score 0):

As per your usecase it seems when you set a value within the element associated with the text **Check-in** the same gets automatically populated with in the element associated with the text **Check-out**. To set a different date within the element associated with the text **Check-out** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.expedia.co.in/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#tab-flight-tab-hp"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flight-departing-hp-flight']//span[@class='label' and text()='Departing']//following::input[1]"))).send_keys("08/06/2019")
  returning = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flight-returning-hp-flight']//span[@class='label' and text()='Returning']//following::input[1]")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','09/06/2019')", returning)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: expedia]

Comment: Those locators are very brittle and setting the value with JS is short cutting any checks the page may have in the UI and is not a best practice, let alone a good practice. You should interact with the UI as a customer would unless it's absolutely not possible.

Comment: I got the **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="btn-primary btn-action gcw-submit" type="submit"> is not clickable at point (182,495) because another element <td> obscures it** error because the date is overlapping the search button

Comment: @Mrsreez In my answer I have dealt with all `<input>` fields and none of the elements have the attribute `type="submit"`. Not sure why you are seeing this error.